# what does WordPress wp_localize_script do?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, localization

can someone explain me what `wp_localize_script()` do?
I don't understand what it does in the first place even I have read it in the WP Codex.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a support request for a third party software, here namely Wordpress. For these please first use the vendors resources like the Wordpress Codex, Wordpress Support Forums or other support resources that are dedicated to that software in specific.


Comment: This link gives a much better explanation for a beginner than the WordPress documentation: http://pippinsplugins.com/use-wp_localize_script-it-is-awesome/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It lets you use PHP data in the client by printing out a JavaScript object. [From the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script):

> Localizes a script, but only if script has already been added. **Can
>   also be used to include arbitrary Javascript data in a page.**

You use like so:

```
// Register script as per Codex instructions.
// It doesn't have to contain anything but the file must exist
wp_register_script('handle', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/dummy.js');

// Send data to client
wp_localize_script('handle', 'Data', array(
  'url' => home_url(),
));
```

This will print an object in JavaScript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var Data = {"url":"http://..."};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Now in the client you can access that data:

```
console.log(Data.url);
```

It's very useful when you're building plugins so you can separate your client from your server logic instead of mixing JS and PHP all in the same file.