# How to Pass PHP variable to JavaScript similar to WordPress wp_localize_script function

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

WordPress has [wp_localize_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/)() which allows to pass PHP variable directly to JS. User can't see passed data from page source whereas if pass data from PHP to JS then we have to echo that variable for example.

```
<script>
var userName = '<?php echo $username ?>';
</script>
```

The user can manipulate it from browser tools. Do we have any secure way of doing this in core PHP where a user doesn't see or unable to manipulate data passed from PHP to JS directly?

Comment: The user can see the data(view:source). ref: [what does WordPress wp_localize_script do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18694144/what-does-wordpress-wp-localize-script-do)

Comment: any data you send/use/get from js, user can find/see/manipulate

Answer (score 0):

yes you can. you can try to use wp ajax. make a ajax request from javascript to the wordpress system and then on the wp backend system  create a function to reply or send back the data to javascript.
something like this:

```
<script>
    //sending the request to get the username with ajax
    function get_the_username()
    {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url : 'https://yoursite/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            dataType : 'json',
            data : {
                action : 'get_the_username'
            },
            type : 'POST',
            beforeSend : function(){
                //alert("sending:");
            },
            success : function( data ){



            }

        });
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to get a variable from PHP to Javascript is to use JSON data type. Make sure you only display the object(refer to echo $jsonObject).
Convert your variable to JSON by simply putting it in an array example:

```
$myVar = 10;
$jsonObject = json_encode(array(array("myVar" => 10))); //I use two arrays because I will use javascript eval() method.
echo $jsonObject;
```

In javascript, simply get that by using eval() for conversion of the string to a Javascript object

```
$.post(linkToPHPScript,{},function(data){
var myVarInJavascript = eval(data);
myVarInJavascript = myVarInJavascript[0].myVar; //You got your variable here in Javascript
});
```